# Converting utf8 encoded string into string in local 8-bit encoding and replacing unconvertable characters with white space

Tags: c++, string, boost, encoding, utf-8

I need to convert utf-8 string into local 8-bit encoded string (single character is represented by char) and keep the number of characters in the result string the same. So, I want unconvertable characters in the original utf string become the white spaces in the result string. Unfortunately the boost::locale::conv::from_utf does not provide such method of conversion. It provides only two:

```
enum    boost::locale::conv::method_type { boost::locale::conv::skip = 0, boost::locale::conv::stop = 1, boost::locale::conv::default_method = skip }
```

Which means you can either skip an unconvertable character (then the result string would be shorter) or raise an exception.

I found the only way to make conversion to work as I want with boost - iterating over string, converting every single character to local 8-bit encoding, catching an exception during that process and inserting white space manually. However, this methods is not efficient and leads to even more encoding conversions. Here is the code:

```
std::string from_utf8_to_local(
    const std::string& str,
    const std::locale& loc)
{
    std::u32string utext = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char32_t>(str);

    std::string textLocal;
    for(char32_t ch : utext)
    {
        std::string newChar;
        try
        {
            std::u32string convStr;
            convStr += ch;
            std::string utf8Str =
                    boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char>(convStr);

            newChar = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(
                        utf8Str,
                        loc,
                        boost::locale::conv::stop);
        }
        catch(boost::locale::conv::conversion_error& /*error*/)
        {
            newChar = " ";
        }
        textLocal.append(newChar);
    }

    return textLocal;
}
```

The questions are:

Is there is a way to do the same in a proper way with boost or stl?

If there is not, how can I do it with other libraries?

Comment: http://site.icu-project.org/  might have something, have not checked

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows you can use [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to go from UTF-8 to a wide character string (UTF-16). Then you can use [WideCharToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to go from wide characters to whatever encoding you desire (see [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). To get spaces for the unconvertable characters, you would need to use the seventh parameter (lpDefaultChar).

Comment: Well, that would definitely work. It also works almost out the box, which is good.  However, I am not on Windows. Therefore, icu seems to be a better solution for me. It works both for Windows and Linux.
PS. Looks like there is no solution with boost.